# HitCounter results on another page

Tags: php, modx, modx-evolution

Page Hit Counter for EVO implemented...[plugin](https://modx.com/extras/package/pagehitcounter)

And this PHP snippet:

```html
<?php
$prefix = $modx->dbConfig['table_prefix'];
$page = '';
$page_id = isset($id) ? $id : $modx->documentObject['id'];
 
        $sql = "SELECT page_count FROM " .$prefix. "page_hit_counter WHERE page_id ='" .$page_id."'";
        $rs = $modx->db->query($sql);
    $row = $modx->db->getRow($rs);
    $count = $modx->recordCount($rs);
    if ($count < 1) {
                $page .= "Page views: 0";
    } else {
                $page .= "Page views: " . $row['page_count'];
    }
 
return $page;
?>
```

The counter works well for all pages.

Now I want to include the counts on a summary page as well.

For example...
page 1 - counts 4
page 3 - counts 9
page 4 - counts 18

The summary page lists the title and introtext of all those three articles.
Together with that I also want to show the page view counts.

So:
Summary page: synopsis of page 1 (counts 4), synopsis of page 3 (counts 9), synopsis of page 4 (counts 18)

For this I have...

```html
<p><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>[~[+id+]~][!pageCount!]</p>
```

But the output of that is only the title text + [!pageCount!] but no value.

I cannot understand why no value shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the id parameter of the pageCount snippet

```
class="fa fa-eye"></i>[~[+id+]~][!pageCount? &id=`[+id+]`!]</p>
```